# Why can't we use synchronous motors in fan?

Tags: motor, power-electronics, induction-motor, electrical, electric-machine

What type of motor is used in wall mounted fan ? Can synchronous motor with damper winding be used in the same ?

I know single phase induction motor is used in fan. But I am not able to figure out the second part. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A synchronous motor with a damper winding is a wound-field, three phase machine normally found only in power ratings that are several orders of magnitude larger than a wall-mounted fa motor. Such a motor might be used for an induced-draft or forced-draft fan for a large furnace or boiler.